# NFS over wifi very slow

Tags: nfs, fstab

I have a NFS server hooked up to a client over a wireless network (n-router, b/g-client). I have terribly slow transfer rates of around `1.00` to `1.50 MB/s`. I cannot seem to figure out how to improve this.

I have played around with `rsize/wsize` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
My `exports` on the server is the following:

```
cat /etc/exports
<SERVER-DIR> *(rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

On the client side I see this:

```
cat /proc/mounts
<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-DIR> <CLIENT-DIR> nfs4 rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=<CLIENT-IP>,local_lock=none,addr=<SERVER-IP> 0 0
```

Shouldn't be able to achieve up to 6-times higher transfer rates?

For comparison:
Wired (100Mb/s):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=128
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 18.5636 s, 7.2 MB/s
```

Wireless:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=128
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 99.4493 s, 1.3 MB/s
```

Comment: What is the network latency between client and server? Have you tried this over a wired connection? How do you know it's the Wifi that is causing the problem?

Comment: Added wired vs. wireless tests. Running `ping` returns in about 0.75ms.

Comment: What's the signal strength and contention on the Wifi ?

Comment: I think the signal strength is unlikely an issue since I am about 3ft from the router.

Comment: @EEAA your initial answer was a bit condescending in my opinion...

Comment: Not condescending, just the truth. There's not much actually working in your favor with your setup.

Comment: Are both the server and the client wireless? Because 1.25 MB/s is the average transfer rate for wireless-to-wireless with 802.11g.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NFS. Over wireless. Using a b/g client (are you even sure you're linked up a G rates?).

You're going to have a bad time here.

**Even if** you're linked up at the theoretical maximum for 802.11g (54Mbps), and there is *no* RF interference (very unlikely in the 2.4GHz band), you still have a theoretical max of about 6.75MBps. Count in protocol overhead, retransmits at several levels of the stack, and network latency, you should be happy with what you're getting now.

---

Honestly, NFS is a very touchy protocol. It doesn't do well with the lossy, up-and-down nature of wireless connections. At the very best, you'll have poor performance. With a typical wireless connection, you'll have *atrocious* performance, corrupted files, hung mounts, and perhaps worse.

If you need to access storage over wifi, use a different protocol that is a bit more resilient to network issues. CIFS, AFS, Samba, etc. will all do *much* better than NFS.

Comment: @Markus - This was not the answer you wanted to hear. I know. Downvote if you like. That doesn't change the facts that you have a hard (perhaps impossible) road ahead of you if you're hoping to get any more performance out of your current setup.

Comment: Wrong, CIFS/SAMBA will give you half the speed.... and is probably the worst way to go. This is usually suggested by windows users that dont know what they are talking about. Its easy just do a side by side test of them both.

Comment: @ChangosMuertos - There's much more to this than pure speed. I am *not* a windows user. I am very much a linux admin. If you need evidence, look at my [tags](http://serverfault.com/users/20815/eeaa?tab=tags&sort=votes) and see which tags (linux or windows) I have more answers for. That said, regardless of platform, I know a bad architectural decision when I see one, and running NFS over wifi is a perfect example of something that **will** be painful, **will** cause downtime, and **will likely** cause data loss.

Comment: @ChangosMuertos - you know what's funny? This answer has gained two upvotes (+20) since your comment and downvote (-1). :)

Comment: I wouldn't expect corrupted files, at least on any modern client (which should default to hard mounts and tcp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on a Synology Nas, NFS was not reliable, but using a cifs works like a charm.